# Adding vCard data directly to the system Address Book

Tags: objective-c, ios, addressbook

I am designing a QR code reader, and it needs to detect and import contact cards in vCard format (.vcf).

is there a way to add the card data to the system Address Book directly, or do I need to parse the vCard myself and add each field individually?

Comment: There is a function, `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation()` to important VCF data, but it was only added in iOS 5. What version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: Well I am not sure yet about the version probably the latest one. My app will be for iPhone 4 and 4s for now and I am using an iPhone 4s to test it to ios5(and later) should be good thanks

Comment: In what variable type do you have the VCF data? NSData, NSString, or just a path to an actual file?

Comment: It will probably be Nsstring.  any advice ?

Comment: Check my answer! I hope that works.

Comment: It's not Vcard in QR codes, but meCard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeCard.

Answer (score 13):

If you're running on iOS 5 or later, this code should do the trick:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

// This gets the vCard data from a file in the app bundle called vCard.vcf
//NSURL *vCardURL = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] URLForResource:@"vCard" withExtension:@"vcf"];
//CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:vCardURL];

// This version simply uses a string. I'm assuming you'll get that from somewhere else.
NSString *vCardString = @"vCardDataHere";
// This line converts the string to a CFData object using a simple cast, which doesn't work under ARC
CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// If you're using ARC, use this line instead:
//CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(book);
CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData);
for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(book, person, NULL);
}

CFRelease(vCardPeople);
CFRelease(defaultSource);
ABAddressBookSave(book, NULL);
CFRelease(book);
```

Make sure to link to the AddressBook framework in your project.

Comment: I am in a situation where I will be deciding what the QR code data type will be reading , all I know is that the format of the text will be like this :

Comment: BEGIN:VCARD
N;CHARSET=utf-8:<last name>;<first name>;;;
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:<full name>
ORG;CHARSET=utf-8:<company name>
TITLE;CHARSET=utf-8:<title>
TEL;WORK:<telephone number>
TEL;WORK;FAX:<fax number>
EMAIL;INTERNET;WORK;CHARSET=utf-8:<email>
ADR;WORK;CHARSET=utf-8:;;<address including zip code , state and country>
URL;WORK;CHARSET=utf-8:<website>
VERSION:2.1
END:VCARD

now considering that it will be spread on several lines , can I say that it is an NSString or will the NSSstring will only take the first line of this text ? (I am fairly new to objective C )

Comment: NSString can easily store multiple lines of text.

Comment: I used this code but it is not working
First it does not compile this line :
CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

I have to change it to this :
 CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
then when it runs it does crashes at this line :
 for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {

Comment: I used this code but it is not working
First it does not compile this line :
CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

I have to change it to this :
 CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
then when it runs it does crashes at this line :
 for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
it gives the following green error : Tread1:Program Received Signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" any reasons ?

Comment: The bridge code was required because you're using ARC, so that makes sense. Here's the simplest possible problem: are you feeding it a valid vCard string? Or are you just using my placeholder? If you're using the placeholder, that definitely won't work. You need to have a valid vCard string.

Comment: Hello
I do have a VCard String , I changed "__bridge" to "__bridge_retained" and still no luck , it compiles and runs but it does not save in the address book

Comment: I'd like to help more, but it's getting annoying to have to flag all the duplicate questions you're asking. Please stick to this **one** question, and we can try and figure this out.

Comment: CFRelease(person);
 is not required and will crash. Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1

Comment: how about **before** iOS 5?

Answer (score 4):

Carter Allen's answer worked for me except that it caused my app to crash on the final statement `CFRelease(book);`

It turns out that the `CFRelease(person);` statement should be removed. Doing so stopped my app from crashing. See this answer for explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337086/881103

Also checkout The Create Rule and The Get Rule sections on this page https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Answer (score 1):

Contacts is pretty forgiving and will do its best to import your vCard, however it seems that your address is not correct.  There should be 7 parameters, separated by semicolons: PO box, Suite #, street address, city, state, ZIP, country. Most people leave off the PO box (and suite #), which is why a typical address has a semicolon (or two) at the beginning.  If your address is ill-formed, parameters might end up in the wrong places.

The various fields in a vCard are terminated by a `<return>`: @"\r"

You don't need `CHARSET=utf-8`