# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when add vCard data to AddressBook

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, objective-c-2.0, vcf-vcard

I follow this instruction to add vcard data to addressbook, in my project. iOS 5. 
 [Adding vCard data directly to the system Address Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116214/adding-vcard-data-directly-to-the-system-address-book)

The code run ok, and add vcard data to adressbook in my ipad2 and iphone4s, however, xcode show this error:

> thread 1 program received signal: "exc_bad_acess"

Why this error appears?

EDIT: code add.

```
NSString *vCardString = 
@"BEGIN:VCARD\n"
@"N:Paulo;Joao\n"
@"TEL:+44 (0)9999 8888\n"
@"ADR;HOME:;;Flat 2, 43 Howitt Road, Belsize Park;London;;NW34LU;UK\n"
@"ORG:NetTek Ltd;\n"
@"TITLE:Consultant\n"
@"EMAIL:none@none.com\n"
@"URL:www.none.com\n"
@"BDAY:19001010\n"
@"END:VCARD";
CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(book);
CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData);
for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++)
{
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(book, person, NULL);
    CFRelease(person);
}
CFRelease(vCardPeople);    
CFRelease(defaultSource);
ABAddressBookSave(book, NULL);
CFRelease(book);
```

Comment: This error appears when you trying to access memory which already released. Print some code for more details.

Comment: The code i have use, is the same of the link, without this code, my project run ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The problem is with the last line, probably because of ARC.

CFRelease(book);

I commented the line, and the program run normally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you were able to find the problem, however, I just thought I'd let you know that it's not an ARC thing but a memory leak thing. You're over-releasing data the the OS wants to release itself. [Here's an explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209130/iphone-sdk-exc-bad-access-with-cfrelease-for-abaddressbookref/1337086#1337086)

Additionally, please mark the question as answered so you can help other people find the solution. Thank you!