# Crash when call CFRelease(ABAddressBookRef ref)

Tags: ios

This's my code, run the last line `CFRelease(addressBook)`, program crash! help me~!

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

NSMutableArray *groups = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBook)];
NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBook)];

[(NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook)) enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj_g, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    ABRecordRef g = (__bridge ABRecordRef)obj_g;
    NSString *gname = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(g));

    NSMutableArray *gp = [[[NSArray alloc] init] mutableCopy];

    [(NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers(g)) enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj_p, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        ABRecordRef p = (__bridge ABRecordRef)obj_p;
        ABMultiValueRef numbers = ABRecordCopyValue(p, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        NSString *pname = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(p));

        [(NSArray *) CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(numbers)) enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj_n, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSString *pnumber = CFBridgingRelease(CFBridgingRetain(obj_n));

            MasMsContact *new_c = [[MasMsContact alloc] init];
            new_c.name = pname;
            new_c.number = pnumber;
            new_c.group = gname;

            [gp addObject:new_c];
        }];

        CFRelease(numbers);
        CFRelease(p);
    }];

    CFRelease(g);

    [people addObject:[gp copy]];
    [groups addObject:gname];
}];

#warning crash when release addressBook, why ???
if (addressBook) CFRelease(addressBook);
```

[Xcode when crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY65q.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't own `obj_p` or `obj_g` so they're being overreleased when you release their bridged references and then pop out of that enumeration block. You only own core foundation objects if you access them using a `Create` or `Copy`.

Comment: I got it, `obj_p` and `obj_g` not create or copy by me, so crash by release them when release `addressBook`. thank you ~

Answer (score 0):

I'm google this [iPhone SDK: EXC_BAD_ACCESS with CFRelease for ABAddressBookRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209130/iphone-sdk-exc-bad-access-with-cfrelease-for-abaddressbookref)

I have same problem, over release `g` and `p`.